# Titanium SDK: JavaScript -> Scrolling feature does not work

Tags: javascript, scroll, titanium

Trying to make my window scrollable so the user can scroll down and view all contents of the window

```
var eventsWin = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
  title:'More Events',
  layout: 'vertical',
  scrollingEnabled: true,
  backgroundColor:'#fff'
});
```

Checked the Appcelerator Docs and couldn't find anything helpful.

Anyone know how to make the window scrollable??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is add a ScrollView (use Ti.UI.createScrollView) to your window and add your elements to that ScrollView. A window has no 'scrollable' property, but a ScrollView has.

Documentation for the ScrollView object is here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/?mobile=/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollView